# What are the negative effects of running only series LEDs on a constant current driver?

Tags: power-supply, led, circuit-design, lighting

I have torn down a cheap light fixture and am trying to understand the design tradeoffs involved with this low quality device. There are only two components in the light fixture:

1. A constant current LED driver
2. An LED strip whose LEDs are wired in series with no other components

Are there any dangers or tradeoffs in connecting only a string of LEDs to a constant current driver? Will this affect light quality when dimming, or LED lifespan, or anything of that sort?

Comment: In my eyes, this is the ideal way to drive LEDs. The only downsides are that a dimmable constant-current driver is more complicated than PWM dimming, and the driver has to be able to handle the power dissipation.

Answer (score 2):

The main downside is that the driver must be paired with the lights since it provides the current regulation. This is why you see things like strips that can be daisy chained or cut to size use constant voltage and resistors.

For closed or self contained units, the constant current configuration with all series LEDs gives higher efficiency, more even brightness and can be dimmed without using PWM. For this reason you rarely see anything else used in fixtures.